# Can 'be it A or B' mean no matter or whether in this manner?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Can 'be it A or B' mean 'no matter if it's A or B' or 'whether A or B'? For example, is the following sentence correct?

> Be it Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way!

Comment: Yes - but very few native Anglophones would say anything like this in "normal" speech today. It's a dated / formal / literary "subjunctive" construction, best suited to historical novels. We much prefer to use ***if*** or ***whether*** nowadays.

Comment: Yea, I read something like that in a fantasy novel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: The 'Be it (...)' is used correctly, and both interpretations are correct.

> Be it Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way!

is correct and the same as these:

1. No matter if it's Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way!
2. Whether it's Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way!

Also

3. It doesn't matter if it's Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way! (I think grammatically correct but the double 'it' is kind of annoying me personally. Lol.)
4. It doesn't matter whether it's Bleoberis or Brandelis, I'll defeat anyone who stands in my way! (Again double 'it'. Lol.)